# When input has space, the program cannot run properly?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
     char name[30];
     float mark;
}student;

int main()
{
     student *s = malloc(2*sizeof(student));

     //Error check
     if (s == NULL)
     {
          return 1;
     }

     //Input
     for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
     {
          printf("Enter name: ");
          scanf("%[^\n]%*c", (s+i)->name);
          printf("Enter mark: ");
          scanf("%f", &(s+i)->mark);
     }

     //reallocate
     student *m = realloc(s, 4*sizeof(student));

     //Error check
     if (m == NULL)
     {
          free(s);
          return 1;
     }

     //Input
     for (int i = 2; i < 4; i++)
     {
          printf("Enter name: ");
          scanf("%[^\n]%*c", (m+i)->name);
          printf("Enter mark: ");
          scanf("%f", &(m+i)->mark);
     }

     for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
     {
          printf("Student %s has %.2f marks.\n", (m+i)->name, (m+i)->mark);
     }

     free(s);
     free(m);
     return 0;
}
```

At this program, it says ...

```
Enter name:
Enter mark:
```

I entered a name with space, e.g Harry Potter

Then, the next thing it happens is like this ...

```
Enter name: Enter mark:
Enter name: Enter mark:
```

I don't know why? If I type a name without space, it runs okay. I even tried with `fgets((s+i)->name, 30, stdin);`. The same thing happened.

Comment: You get a line feed left-over in stdin.

Comment: Add a space at the start of the format strings for the two `name` input calls, like this: `scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", (s + i)->name);`. There's a duplicate somewhere, I'm sure ...

Comment: The last `free(s);` shall be deleted. `realloc` did that

Comment: Get rid of the nasty `%*c` kludges trying to remove *trailing* whitespace and add a space before the `%` as `" %[^\n]"` to remove *leading* whitespace. The `%f` specifier automatically filters leading whitespace, but `%c` and `%[` do not.

Comment: Wow. It works. The space before %[^\n] thing. Thanks for all of you. What about fgets(). Can I make it work too?

Comment: Yes, but not when you mix it the `scanf`. Use `fgets` for *all* input and if needed use `sscanf` or other function to extract the float. And remove the trailing newlines.